# rosjs_remotelabwidgets contents

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I discovered rosbridge and rosjs several months ago. Today, parsing ros packages, I discovered rosjs_remotelabwidgets. Is it new ? Does it work only for the pr2 or for other platform ? What does it contain?
Sincerely,
BeuBeu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37309/rosjs_remotelabwidgets-contents/) by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi BeuBeu,

The remote lab project has a number of cool widgets to do with robot visualization and control.  However, some of these are written in a manner that makes them difficult to reuse.  There is a current effort (within the last few weeks) at Bosch and Willow to begin to modularise many of the web components that we have til now written.  We are not writing new widgets per se, but they are being split up so it should make it a lot easier for people to, for example, throw on a PR2 visualization onto their web page.

With regards to the robots that they work for - that's on a per-widget basis.  Some of the widgets, such as the simple joystick widget, merely publish to a particular topic.  Other widgets are clearly PR2 specific, such as the PR2 visualization.  This will only work if it's receiving PR2 info on the /tf topic.

The best places to keep up to date are the following:

- rosbridge.org: We are working on a
  new, industrial-strength rosbridge,
  that will be released with
  first-class support from Willow.
  rosbridge.org is a good place to keep
  up to date for news regarding the
  release schedule and protocol
  enhancements
- https://github.com/rosjs/rosjs: This
  is where the heavyweight ros.js and
  javascript widgets will be mostly
  hosted.
- rosbridge conf. call: There is a
  weekly conference call for interested
  parties.  If you wish to contribute
  to the effort, then you're very
  welcome to join!
- ROSDojo: Many of the Brown ROS web
  interfaces can be found in the
  experimental/ROSDojo project in the
  brown-ros-pkg

There will be a few announcements towards the end of the summer relating to rosbridge, rosjs, and javascript widgets.

Cheers,

Jon

---

Originally posted by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) with karma: 431 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1